# Hitting 2 URLS using an anchor tag in Laravel

Tags: laravel, anchor

I have got an ancor link tag on the DOM and would like to hit 2 URLS once it is clicked, the endpoints are **route('b2c.receipt')** and **route('b2c.flushData')**

```
<a href="{{ route('b2c.receipt') }}"> Download Receipt</a>
```

Comment: What's the use case for this? I am assuming you want to do some kind of cleanup. If this is the case, why not call the cleanup inside the first method itself?

Comment: Sure have to do some cleanup,, I have another function that depends on the data in the 1st method,, thats why I want to flush Data afer clicking the anchor tag..

Comment: If you show us some code, we would be able to help you better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't really be able to do this with a raw anchor tag.

Given the name of your second route, `flushData`, it may be that you can incorporate the "flush data" logic into the first route's controller function.

If not, you're going to need to use JavaScript to fire off two AJAX requests.

Comment: Thats fine but am not sure if the AJAX will open a PDF document since the data since the link is  route('b2c.receipt')  is supposed to open a document,,

Comment: @Martin You could open that one with `window.open`, perhaps. Or do the `flushData` first, then redirect with `window.location.href`.

Comment: Sure,, but I cant flushData 1st before opening the PDF document route('b2c.receipt').. I need to open the PDF , then call flushData on the same event ..

Comment: Then put the `flushData` logic in the PDF generation route, after it's generated but before the response is sent.